# Block function and wait for event C#

Tags: c#, events, .net-4.0, thread-synchronization

i would like to block a function and wait for an event then continue , in my case the pseudo-code that i want to have when i click a button:

- pop up messagebox
- wait for the event click in datagridview
- pop up messagebox2
- wait for the event click in datagridview
- pop up a yes/no messagebox
- execute another function

but the actual code do not wait for  autoevent.Set() function so the functions called by the threads remains blocked while i want to block the main function.

i tried ManualResetEvent and AutoResetEvent, this is the code that i used for AutoResetEvent :

```
 public partial class person : Form
    {

AutoResetEvent auto = new AutoResetEvent(false);  

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           int old_id, new_id;

            //dataGridView1.ClearSelection(); 
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(th_remove));
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(th_replace));

            t1.Start(); 
           old_id = (int)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value; 

           t2.Start();
           new_id = (int)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value;

            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Remplacer", "Vous êtes sûr de vouloir remplacer ?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                db.replace("person", new_id, old_id); 
            }
           }

        private  void th_replace()
        {
            auto.WaitOne();  
            MessageBox.Show("Seléctionnez la ligne remplaçante");
        }

        private  void th_remove()
        {
            auto.WaitOne();          
            MessageBox.Show("Seléctionnez la ligne à supprimer");
        }


        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
             auto.Set();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add a synchronization object and use [Monitor's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x090d6tf) methods `Wait` and `Pulse` on your sync object. That is you need to call `Pulse` in your event handler and `Wait` in your synchronous method. But make sure your event does not occur before you enter the `Wait` state... =)
Good luck!

Comment: So do you think it's reasonable to block a UI thread until something happens, with no way of the user closing the application, moving the windows etc?

Comment: If I get the code correctly, @geogeek doesn't block the UI thread as `th_replace` and `th_remove` are called on separate threads. And I agree with you that he should not block the UI thread. Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Comment: i was missing the piece of working the whole function on a new thread different of that of the UI, during debugging i have had some UI freezes but now it works good when i use a new thread

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to block a function and wait for an event then continue

That's basically not how event-driven GUIs work. You shouldn't block the UI thread - it will stop the screen from refreshing, the window from being dragged, closed etc.

Instead, you should disable all actions that you don't want to be available while other processing is going on, and when the events occur, call back into the UI thread (e.g. using `Control.Invoke`) re-enable the relevant controls, and continue with your logic.

C# 5 will make a lot of this easier with async methods, as then you can write synchronous-looking code which "awaits" operations completing without blocking the thread - but you'll still need to work out what to disable/enable when.